# Django forms - disable escaping for custom css on errors

Tags: html, css, django, twitter-bootstrap-3

I created custom css for my django form errors (to work with bootstrap)

```
from django.forms.util import ErrorList

class CustomErrorList(ErrorList):
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.as_divs()

    def as_divs(self):
        if not self: return ''
        return '<div class="alert alert-danger"><ul class="errorlist list-unstyled">%s</ul></div>' % ''.join(['<li class="error">%s</li>' % e for e in self])

class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        exclude = ['author']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PostForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.error_class = CustomErrorList
        self.auto_id = False

        for key in self.fields:
            self.fields[key].widget.attrs.update({'class' : 'form-control'})
```

But, django now auto escapes the html

[image]

I guess it's not too hard to make it as safe in the template:

```
{{ form.name.errors | safe }}
```

however, that's kind of annoying. Is there another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`django.utils.safestring.mark_safe`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.safestring.mark_safe):

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

...

class CustomErrorList(ErrorList):
    ...

    def as_divs(self):
        if not self:
            return ''
        return mark_safe(
            '<div class="alert alert-danger">'
            '<ul class="errorlist list-unstyled">%s</ul>'
            '</div>' % ''.join('<li class="error">%s</li>' % e for e in self)
        )
```